# Query App Permissions for Other Apps on Android

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, user-permissions

[image]

How do I implement this on android? Not the design but the functionality. Is there a way I can get/change permissions that other apps have from my app?
For instance, get a list of all the permissions Facebook has and remove or add certain permissions.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: You can use `PackageManager` to find out what permissions another app requests in the manifest. You cannot add or remove permissions from other apps.

Comment: The ScreenShot is an app that implements that. You can toggle the switch to revoke or give permissions for any resource.